# Table layout for social app in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I was trying to see if we can avoid data de-normalization using YB’s secondary index , primary table is something like below :

```
CREATE TABLE posts_by_user(
    user_id   bigint,
    post_id     bigserial,
    group_ids   bigint[] null,
    tag_ids     bigint[] null,
    content     text null,
    ....
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, post_id)
)
```

-- there could be multiple group ids(up to 20) which user can select to publish his/her post in

-- there could be multiple tag ids(up to 20) which user can select to publish his/her post with

This structure makes fetching by `user_id` easier but, suppose I want to fetch by group_id(s) or tag_id(s), then either I will need to de-normalize it into secondary tables using YB transaction, which will require additional app logic and also could lead to performance issues because data will be written into multiple nodes based hash primary keys(group_ids and tag_ids).
Or I could use a secondary index  to avoid writing additional logic, I have the following doubts regarding that :
YB stable version 2.8 does not allow creating a secondary index on array columns using GIN , any rough timelines it will be available as stable release version ?
will this also suffer same performance issue since multiple index will be updated at the time of client call in multiple nodes based on partition key group_id(s) or tag_id(s) ?
Other ideas are also most welcome for saving data to enable faster queries based on user_id(s), group_id(s), tag_id(s) in a scalable way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the GIN index is that it won't be sorted on disk by the timestamp.

You have to create an index for `(user_id, datetime desc)`.
While for groups you can maintain a separate table, with a primary key of `(group_id desc, datetime desc, post_id desc)`. The same for tags.
And on each feed-request, you can make multiple queries for, say, 5 posts on each user_id or group_id and then merge them in the application layer.

This will be the most efficient since all records will be sorted on-disk and in-memory at write-time.